# Oracle error: Invalid Identifier

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to access and update Oracle database with python. Below is my code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy
import math
#import pandasql

conn_str = 'sahil/sahil@52.20.141.126:1521/xe'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()

def update_output_table(customer_id_list,column_name,column_vlaue_list) :
    num_rows_to_add = len(customer_id_list)
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
    c = conn.cursor()

    for i in range(0,num_rows_to_add,1) :
        c.execute("""UPDATE output SET """+column_name+""" = %s WHERE customer_id = %s""" %(column_vlaue_list[i],customer_id_list[i]))
    print "Completed updating " + column_name

    conn.commit()

total_transaction_df = pd.read_sql("""select distinct b.customer_id,count(a.transaction_id) as total_transaction from transaction_fact a,customer_dim b where a.customer_id = b.customer_id group by b.customer_id""",conn)

# Update this details to the output table
update_output_table(list(total_transaction_df['CUSTOMER_ID']),'TOTAL_TRANSACTION',list(total_transaction_df['TOTAL_TRANSACTION']))

english_movies_df = pd.read_sql("""select b.customer_id, count(a.product_id) as "ENGLISH_MOVIES" from transaction_fact a inner join customer_dim b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id where a.product_id like 'E%' group by b.customer_id""",conn)

# Update this details to the output table
update_output_table(list(english_movies_df['CUSTOMER_ID']),'ENGLISH_MOVIES',list(english_movies_df['ENGLISH_MOVIES']))

hindi_movies_df = pd.read_sql("""select b.customer_id, count(a.product_id) as "HINDI_MOVIES" from transaction_fact a inner join customer_dim b on     a.customer_id = b.customer_id where a.product_id like 'H%' group by b.customer_id""",conn)

# Update this details to the output table
update_output_table(list(hindi_movies_df['CUSTOMER_ID']),'HINDI_MOVIES',list(hindi_movies_df['HINDI_MOVIES']))

most_popular_genre_df = pd.read_sql("""select x.customer_id, x.genre as "MOST_POPULAR_GENRE",x.count1 from (select b.customer_id,c.genre,count(a.transaction_id) as count1, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.customer_id order by count(a.transaction_id) desc,c.genre) as Rank1 from transaction_fact a inner join customer_dim b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id inner join product_dim c on a.product_id = c.product_id group by b.customer_id, c.genre)x where x.Rank1 = 1""",conn)

# Update this details to the output table
update_output_table(list(most_popular_genre_df['CUSTOMER_ID']),'MOST_POPULAR_GENRE',list(most_popular_genre_df['MOST_POPULAR_GENRE']))

conn.close()
```

Whole script is getting executed except for the last call to `update_output_table` where it is giving `ORA-00904 : 'UNCONVENTIONAL' invalid identifier`.

I have passed the correct column names. Below is my code for creating `output` table :

```
create table output
(
    customer_id integer,
    total_transaction integer,
    english_movies integer,
    hindi_movies integer,
    most_popular_genre varchar2(30),
    last_transaction_date date,
    overall_score integer
)
```

`UNCONVENTIONAL` is the very first entry for my fact table product category. Is it picking `UNCONVENTIONAL` as my column name instead of `MOST_POPULAR_GENRE` ? If yes then how come?

Note : I am a newbie so please bare if it's a silly doubt.

Comment: do you have only one table? show your complete DB schema, so that we can help you.

Comment: Hi @Wasi Ahmad. The problem got resolves. Instead of %s, I had to put '%s' since I am inserting a string into database. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no mention of the field `UNCONVENTIONAL` in your code, its difficult to point out the problem. But the error message tells a lot of thing. I encourage you to understand the error message so that it helps you in future.

> Oracle / PLSQL: ORA-00904 Error Message

**Description**

When you encounter an `ORA-00904` error, the following error message will appear:

```
ORA-00904: invalid identifier
```

**Cause**

You tried to execute a SQL statement that included an **invalid column name or the column name is missing**. This commonly occurs when you reference an invalid alias in a `SELECT` statement.

**Resolution**

Rewrite your SQL to include a valid column name. To be a valid column name the following criteria must be met:

- The column name must begin with a letter.
- The column name can not be longer than 30 characters.
- The column name must be made up of alphanumeric characters or the following special characters: `$, _, and #`. If the column name uses any other characters, it must be enclosed in double quotation marks.
- The column name can not be a reserved word.

Let's look at an example of how to resolve an ORA-00904 error.

```
SQL> SELECT contact_id AS "c_id", last_name, first_name
  2  FROM contacts
  3  ORDER BY "cid";
ORDER BY "cid"
         *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "cid": invalid identifie
```

This error was created by aliasing a column, but then mistyping the alias later. In this example, we created the alias called "c_id" for the contact_id, but then called it as "cid" in the ORDER BY clause.

To resolve this error, we can modify our SELECT statement to use the correct alias name in the ORDER BY clause as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT contact_id AS "c_id", last_name, first_name
  2  FROM contacts
  3  ORDER BY "c_id";

10 rows selected
```

Reference: [Oracle / PLSQL: ORA-00904 Error Message](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00904.php).

Comment: Can you suggest what is wrong with below lines of code : update_output2_table(list(location_genre_df['LOCATION']),list(location_genre_df['GENRE'])) c.execute("""UPDATE output2 SET location_genre = %s WHERE location = %s""" %(column_vlaue_list[i],location_list[i])) Why is it taking value inside a column name as a column name?

Comment: i am not actually getting it. the statement is not clear to me!

Comment: I got it. When you are inserting a string into database, you have to write '%s' instead of %s. That's what creating the problem.

Comment: @SahilDoshi you are right. i didn't notice that you only used %s. if my answer helped you in some way, you can accept it as the answer. happy coding :)